# python openpyxl: hide all rows from to the end

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I am looking for a method for hiding all rows in an excel sheet using python's openpyxl module. I would like, for example, to hide all rows from the 10th one to the end. Is it possible in openpyxl? For instance in xlsxwriter there is a way to hide all unused rows. So I am looking for a similar funcitonality in openpyxl, but I can not find it in docs or anywhere else, so any help will be much appreciated.

I know it can be easily done by iterating over rows, but this approach is awfully slow, so I would like to find something faster.

Comment: Please post your solution thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such feature at the moment in the `openpyxl`. However, this can be easily done in an optimized way in the `xlsxwriter` module.

Comment: It is possible but not very useful - all rows will be saved. A simple example:
for row in range(sheet.max_row, 1048576+1):
   sheet.row_dimensions[i].height = None  # important
   sheet.row_dimensions[i].hidden = True
Results: hidden_by_excel.xlsx 12KB, hidden_by_openpyxl.xlsx 2 597 KB

Answer (score 0):

Look like I'm a bit late but here goes:

you can hide all of the rows from the 10th to the end with the following code:

```
for row in range(10:ws.max_row):
    ws.row_dimensions[row].hidden= True
```